# Tool for tightening an anchor bolt

Tags: tools

After my first encounter with sleeve anchor, I think I need a good tool to tighten the nut.

May I know what is best tool?

I bought a [standalone M10 ratchet wrench](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008MMDR6W) but is there a tool that add more power? :D

Is there a torque wrench for small scale usage? Do I really need a torque wrench?

Comment: When you say "standalone", is this to say that you have one that is open faced and closed face like the following: http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/tools/Ratchets-Sockets/wrenches-combination/metric-short-combination-wrench-1210mt-5-long-10-mm-opening-full-polished?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=CjwKEAjw67SvBRC1m5zPv4GboAUSJAB6MJlk_gmTqe8reQXZVkeUymsVRbrpg1IaHoSOcHdBML1L3hoC2rjw_wcB  ?

Comment: Example : http://www.amazon.com/a12052400ux0298-Reverse-Ratchet-Combination-Spanner/dp/B008MMDR6W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1441645446&sr=8-1&keywords=10+ratchet+wrench

Answer (score 2):

Use a deep well socket and ratcheting set.  Given that this is a 10mm nut, you don't want too much torque.  Assuming you don't crush the surface you are tightening to and have a sufficient washer, you need to be concerned with torquing the bolt off.  In certain cases, I've taken a 1inch diameter by 1.5ft lead pipe and put it on the end to get extra torque, but I advise against this if you don't have a feel for how much torque you are applying.  You can find small scale torque wrenches, but if you are going to do so, I suggest you look up the recommended torques to apply to the bolt you are using (you need to know what type of bolt it is).

Comment: I'm looking at amazon listed torque wrenches, they are all in imperial scale, I am on metric system =x

Can recommend  one for simple home usage?

Comment: I think if you find one that is rated to go down to 10ft-lbs (120inch-lbs) is what you'll need.  Lowest 10mm torque is 17ft-lbs.  This is really small, by the way.  Just find one (Tekton is a favorite) that matches the socket set that you have and goes low enough for what you are looking for.  Remember if you are going to torque at the lower end of the torque range of the wrench, you need to tighten very slowly to feel the wrench break ("click").

Comment: Any link? I am new to this and the imperial scale is not helping.

Comment: Should I get a 3/8" or 1/2"? I plan to keep it for every day home use.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the longer lever (pipe) you put on the end of that wrench, the more it will distort your sense of how much torque you're actually applying.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/TEKTON-1230-Socket-10-19mm-Sockets/dp/B000K2IG36/ref=sr_1_13?ie=UTF8&qid=1441706371&sr=8-13&keywords=metric+socket+set and http://www.amazon.com/TEKTON-24330-8-Inch-Torque-Wrench/dp/B00FMPKAD0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1441706492&sr=8-1&keywords=3+8+torque+wrench&pebp=1441706491101&perid=0AGXSWT0DR1BBCA2SNH7